# Making a DIV fill the remainder of the page without JavaScript and absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to get this DIV to fill the remainder of the page without JavaScript and absolute positioning?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            #title_image { float: left; margin: 1em; }
            #title { float: left; margin: 1em; }
            #content { background-color: #808277; clear: both; color: #FEFDDE; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img id="title_image" src="helloworld_small.jpg" />
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <h3>Home of the Hello World site!</h3>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            Hello World
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I set the `height` to `100%` it's a tidge taller than the viewport. I don't guess that's all that surprising because it's filling 100% plus the height of the content above it. When I set the `position` to `relative` and the `bottom` to `0` that just makes it the height of the content. I don't guess that's all that surprising either because I think the `bottom` is only used in `absolute` positioning. When I wrap the header content in a `div` and make set its `height` to `20%` and then set the `content` div's `height` to `80%` it ends up rendering a lot like just setting the `content` div's `height` to `80%`.

Comment: Is the header content's height static?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90178/make-a-div-fill-the-remaining-screen-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of creating a JSFiddle of what I think you meant, I also html5'd it up. Is this close?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bushwazi/5A99H/)

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
hgroup {
    padding:2% 1em;
    background:#0f0;
    height:20%;
    display:block;    
}
article {
    background-color:#808277;
    color:#FEFDDE;
    height:72%;
    padding:2% 1em;
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look in this website for better understanding.

> http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

This might help you.